# Problem with not being able to open file after downloading

Tags: python, praw

I have a script which is used to do some scraping on Reddit.

```
import praw
import requests

def reddit_scrape():
    count = 0
    for submission in subreddit.new(limit = 100): 
        if (is_known_id(submission_id = submission.id)): 
            print('known')
            continue

        save_id(submission.id)
        save_to_dict(id = submission.id, txt = submission.title)
        img_data = requests.get(submission.url).content
        with open(submission.id, 'wb') as handler:
            handler.write(img_data)
        print(submission.url)

        count += 1
        if count >= 3: break
```

However, when I try to open the file saved as handler, it does not have an extension and I am not able to open it.

I have no idea what is causing this issue, as it was working perfectly a while ago.

Feel free to let me know if I am missing any info, as this is just part of the entire script.

Comment: Can you open it if you rename it to the correct extension? Does `submission.id` contain an extension?

Comment: The reason it has no extension is because you haven't specified one in the file name. Try `with open(f'{submission.id}.ext', 'wb')`, where 'ext' is your desired file extension.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However, the extension will vary based on the downloaded file, because it could be a gif, jpg or png. Previously, when I ran this particular function, it was automatically appending the extensions for me, so I had no idea why it wouldn't add the extension when I ran it just now.